# Ubuntu doesn't recognize virtual cores

Tags: 20.04, grub2, intel, intel-cpu

I have a little problem... The virtualization is activated in the Bios an it is also detected by lscpu (Virtualization: VT-x) but Threads per Core is only one an also htop only shows me half of the cores...
I am running a dual socket setup on Intel Xeon E5540 (4 cores, 8 threads)...

Here is the output of `/etc/default/grub` if it is any helpful...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mys8X.png)

I hope anyone can help me ;)

Comment: If this an installed system?  *live* or *live* with persistence?      Your file doesn't match an installed system  (*I'd not expect `maybe-ubiquity` on an installed system, nor server etc*..)

Comment: Yes its an installed system. `maybe-ubuquity` was added by the installation...

Comment: Is Ubuntu Server installed on bare metal or in a virtualization layer? Have you confirmed that both sockets are being used? Is this a new installation on a new server or an old server? 

Comment: Virtualization ≠ multi-threaded cores. Virtualization has to do with virtual machines. It's unclear what the screenshot of your terminal showing your GRUB settings has to do with this, but please don't upload pictures of your terminal. Pictures of text are hard to read and impossible to work with.   You should copy/paste and you can use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to retain monospace formatting and line breaks. This enables us to accurately parse the information you provide. Your BIOS needs to have Intel Hyper-Threading enabled.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Yes hyper-threading is enabled. And after I removed maybe-ubuquity all 16 cores are showing :)